# Offers and deals implementation in Push notifications in Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-push-notification

I have implemented push notification using fcm, but I want the notification to be similar like Flipkart, If I post some any offers and deals to the user, the user must redirect to that page if he click on the push notification. How can  I implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you need an unique tag eg. notification_type or type etc inside the payload that is received in notification this type used to direct the PendingIntent to where it should be redirected.So assuming that you are familiar with FirebaseMessagingService you are managing the notification inside the class which extends `FirebaseMessagingService`  now inside that class define the object of `PendingIntent` here is the step

```
 private PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
```

Handle notification like this

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See showChatNotification method below.

    //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    // Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    //Logger.d(TAG + " getData: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    //Logger.d(TAG + " getData: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        setNotification(data);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notificaiton");
    }
}
```

Here i created method `setNotification(data);`  to perfrom event on notification received

```
 private void showOtherNotification(Map<String, String> data) {
    Date now = new Date();
    uniqueId = now.getTime();

        if (data.containsKey("type")) {
            switch (data.get("type")) {
                case "today_diss":
                    navigetToTodaysDisFragment(data);
                    break;
                case "questionnaire":
                    navigetToQuestionaire(data);
                    break;
                default:
                    navigateToHome();
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            navigateToHome();
        }



    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    //Large Icon
    Bitmap remote_picture = null;
    try {
        if (data.containsKey("image")) {
            if (!data.get("image").isEmpty()) {
                remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                        (InputStream) new URL(data.get("image")).getContent());

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // this is a my insertion looking for a solution
    int icon = getNotificationIcon();
    if (data.containsKey("image") && remote_picture != null) {
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"default")
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.get("message"))))
                .setContentText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.get("message")))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(remote_picture)
                        .setBigContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setSummaryText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.get("message"))));
    } else {
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"default")
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.get("message"))))
                .setContentText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(data.get("message")))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    }


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify((int) uniqueId, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

Here i also provide you the solution to manage rich notification if your notification contains image you can display on the notification bar

Now if you can see there is peace of code

```
  case "today_diss":
                    navigetToTodaysDisFragment(data);
                    break;
                case "questionnaire":
                    navigetToQuestionaire(data);
                    break;
                default:
                    navigateToHome();
                    break;
```

This is the main solution you need this methods will redirect you too the screen where you want to redirect so here I am giving you the example of `navigateToHome();`

This method will redirect you to the HomeScreen

```
   private void navigateToHome() {
    Intent intentToEventPage = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, DashActivity.class);
    intentToEventPage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentToEventPage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) uniqueId /* Request code */, intentToEventPage, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

such way you can modify the `pendingIntent` as per your requirement to redirect to the desired activity or view

Comment: Thanks for the solution will let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Tirumalesh kallepalli you can achieve this by using PendingIntent from your FirebaseMessagingService class

Example

```
    public class FcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private String msg;
    NotificationHelper notificationHelper;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    JSONObject object = null;
     try {
            Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
            object = new JSONObject(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        sendNotification(object);
  }

 private void sendNotification(JSONObject object) {

 //Here You can give your screen name whatever you want to open
 //Instead of HomeActivity.class you can replace your activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        try {
            msg = object.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Uri defaultSoundUri = 
        RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
          NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Just give the name of the activity in the Pending Intent nothing else i hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello @Tirumalesh kallepalli whenever you implement this and if you have faced any problem then please contact me and If your issue is solved than please accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution will let you know if it works